# using PrimeFaces upload file get garbled character

Tags: forms, jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I use primeface upload file , the code about form like this

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ....
    <pf:inputTextare value="#{bean.text}"/>
    <pf:fileupload value="#{bean.file}" mode="sample"/>
    <pf:commandButton actionLister="#{bean.save}"/>
    ....
</h:form>
```

the bean code is simple like this

```
public class bean{
    private String text;
    private UploadedFile file;
    //getter and setter methods...
    public void save(){
       //save file and text in DB
    }
}
```

in form when I use enctype="multipart/form-data" I can upload the file successfully.  But the text are Illegal characters. But when I do not use "multipart/form-data" in form the text character is right but the file can not be uploaded.
I have searched about "multipart/form-data",uploading a file "multipart/form-data"is necessary for a form(maybe is not correct :) ) ,but how can I solve the Illegal character?(or can you tell me another way to upload file without "multipart/form-data"?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve this issuse, in the manage bean you need transcoding you get from the form.Like this.

```
String youGetFromPage=new String(youGetFromPage.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
```